# Django read only/view permission on models + row level permission

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I am making a photo sharing application using Django Framework.
I am stuck with 2 problems

1) The user who has uploaded photo can only edit that photo. Other users cannot edit that photo. But can see/view list of photos by all users. and also they can add any photo under their username

2) I need to define a row level permissions for one of the functionality. Eg - Rating of photo by other users. Now, that u can only do when u give write permissions to that user. So if i give write permissions, user would be able to edit other stuff also (name, album etc..) which i do not want. I only want that user can only edit ratings.

I tried searching for the answer but i am not able to get any.

Would be glad if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

1) In your picture class, you probably have a variable that will hold the username of the person who uploaded the picture. In the editing view, make sure that you aren't confining the editing ability to that username.

2) Look at the Django Tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/ and head over to the part where they explain how to create the voting in the Poll app. This should give you a good foundation for your project.

Comment: I tried but i am not able to do that. I looked at Django tutorial, but could not find the view only permission documentation. Do u have any idea about that?